# Conversion de Python a Java

Tags: java, python

estoy resolviendo una tarea en java. He visto un código en Python que me ayuda a crear el tablero. El problema que no se como seria la conversión de unos métodos de python a java. ¿shelf es como el this en java?. Gracias de antemano.

```
class Board(object):

    def __init__(self, width: int, heigth: int):
        self.width = width
        self.heigth = heigth
        self._board = None

    @property
    def board(self):
        if not self._board:
            self._board = [[True for column in range(self.heigth)] for row in range(self.width)]
        return self._board
    
    def draw_block(self, x: int, y: int):
        if x < 0 or y <0:
            raise IndexError(f"Combination of x,y:{x},{y} out of range.")
        self.board[x][y] = False
    
    def get_cell(self, x: int, y: int):
        if x < 0 or y <0:
            raise IndexError(f"Combination of x,y:{x},{y} out of range.")
        return self.board[x][y]

    def is_cell_available(self, x: int, y: int):
            return 0<=x<self.width and 0<=y<self.heigth and self.board[x][y]
        
    def copy(self):
        return Board(self.width, self.heigth)
```

Comment: Sí, `self` es como `this` en Java, con la diferencia de que en python ese parámetro debe declararse explícitamente en cada método, mientras que en Java es implicito (no se declara). Por desgracia no es la única diferencia entre Python y java. En el código que pones el método `board` hace uso de list-comprehensions que no tienen equivalente en java (crean listas en una sola linea usando una expresión que contiene `for`, pero no son un bucle normal). Quizás puedes plantear alguna pregunta más concreta.

Comment: ¿entonces como sería ese método en Java?. Perdona es que ando perdido. Gracias.

Comment: @Rodry Si te mandan una tarea que es escribir código en Java, y alguien hace el código en Python y otra persona te lo traduce a Java... ¿Cuál es el propósito de la tarea?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la estrategia no es tanto "convertir" como "comprender". Una vez comprendes lo que hace este código, debes expresarlo en Java usando la sintaxis y facilidades que este lenguaje te da. Puedo explicarte el código en Python, pero escribirlo en Java es tarea tuya.

Por otro lado, temo que una vez comprendas lo que hace este código, decidas finalmente no usarlo porque no creo que se adapte a la tarea que tienes entre manos.

### Explicación del código Python.

El código python que proporcionas sirve para crear una clase llamada `Board`. Java también tiene clases (de hecho en java todo son clases, no hay otra forma de programarlo).

La misión de la clase `Board` es almacenar una matriz rectangular de booleanos. Se entiende que cada elemento de la matriz representa una casilla de un tablero, y el booleano `True` o `False` representa si la casilla está disponible o no.

La clase en cuestión ofrece métodos para:

- Inicializar el tablero (todas las casilla disponibles). Esta funcionalidad está repartida entre el método `__init__()`, que equivale al constructor de Java y que en este caso se limita a guardar las dimensiones del tablero dentro del objeto, pero no a crear el tablero en sí, y el método `board()` que actúa como una propiedad (lo que en Java sería un *getter*). Éste sí que crea la matriz que representa al tablero y la inicializa con todo `True`.
- Recuperar la matriz cuadrada que representa a ese tablero (¿quizás para dibujarla? No se sabe para qué). Esto lo hace `board()`. Al ser una property, desde fuera del objeto se puede usar `objeto.board` para recuperar la matriz interna (almacenada realmente en el atributo `._board`. Esto es algo así como un atributo privado en Java, con su *getter*. Pero además en este código python la matriz se crea cuando la propiedad es accedida por primera vez y no antes.
- Marcar cualquier casilla del tablero como no disponible. Esto lo hace el método `draw_block()`, cuyo nombre no es precisamente el más apropiado para deducir qué hace.
- Obtener el valor booleano de una casilla cualquiera. Esto lo hace el método `get_cell()`
- Verificar si las coordenadas de una casilla son válidas (no se salen de las dimensiones del tablero) y además está libre. Esto lo hace el método `is_cell_available()`.
- Crear otro tablero igual a éste, en cuanto a sus dimensione. Esto lo hace el método `copy()`.

### Crítica adicional

Este código python no es de muy buena calidad. Tiene bastantes fallos en mi opinión:

- `copy()` no crea una copia del tablero, solo de sus dimensiones (los valores de las casills no se copia, ni la matriz interna)
- `draw_block()` y `get_cell()` no verifican correctamente si la casilla está dentro del tablero. Solo verifican que las coordenadas sean positivas.
- Mucha funcionalidad es redundante. Si puedes obtener el estado de una casilla ¿para qué se necesita entonces la función `is_cell_available()`? El valor retornado sería el mismo que el de `get_cell()`. Si puedes obtener el tablero entero a través de `objeto.board` ¿para qué las funciones que permiten cambiar sus elementos? En realidad creo que la matriz debería ser siempre una propiedad privada, sin opción de obtener esa matriz desde fuera, para así controlar los accesos a los elementos y verificar que están dentro de los límites del tablero.